# Load PDF in modal with Laravel routes and vuejs axios

Tags: html, laravel, pdf, routes, vue.js

I am trying to generate a PDF and open a modal on button click.
In the modal the generated PDF should be loaded in the DOM.

To generate the PDF I use axios:

```
axios.post('/preview', formData)
.then(function (response) {
     this.previewPdf = response.data;
}.bind(this));
```

The generated PDF name is returned in the controller and saved in the `this.previewPdf` variable.

Then I use laravel URL wildcards to load the PDF in the modal.

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <embed :src="'/preview/' + previewPdf" width="100%" height="600" type='application/pdf'>
</div>
```

And the controller for the route `/preview/{pdfname}` returns the PDF.

```
return Storage::disk('local')->get('temppdf/' . $pdfname);
```

However if I open the modal the PDF seems to be loaded (Network preview):

`%PDF-1.7
%����
2 0 obj
<</Type/XObject`
etc.

But the modal just shows an empty `<embed>`. Although the src of it is correctly `src="preview/pdfname.pdf"`.

What could cause this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem.

In the controller where I return my PDF I needed to return a header.. The content-type without the header before was just html.

With this line of code it works:

```
return response(Storage::disk('local')->get('temppdf/' . $pdfname), 200)
              ->header('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
```